# how to store var_dump data in variables

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I have the following `var_dump` data in my console. i want to store them in variables.

```
    array(1) {
      ["pupload"]=>
       array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "profile.jpg"
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(45) "C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAF1C.tmp"
        ["error"]=>
        int(0)
        ["size"]=>
        int(114348)
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

My code

```
    $variable =   var_dump($_FILES);
    echo $variable;
```

Comment: that is an array, what u need?

Comment: I want to store "name", "type" and "tmp_name" in variables.

Comment: u r using var_dump for your array() right, and its associative array..

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right, but you want to copy it into code again, right? Maybe look at `var_export`

Comment: it didn't work.


 my code:-

    $your_variable =   var_dump($_FILES);

    $name = $your_variable['pupload']['name'];
    $type =$your_variable['pupload']['type'];
    $tmp_name = $your_variable['pupload']['tmp_name'];

  echo  $name.' : '.$type.' : '.$tmp_name;

Comment: Oh man i said replace the variable names. so it should be `$name = $_FILES['pupload']['name']; $type =$_FILES['pupload']['type']; $tmp_name = $_FILES['pupload']['tmp_name']; echo $name.' : '.$type.' : '.$tmp_name;`

Comment: @saqibkifayat Do you want the real actual array here or just the array output as string?

Comment: @Anant thanks that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you said :- `I want to store "name", "type" and "tmp_name" in variables`**

And you tell that your variable is `$_FILES`. So do like below:-

```
$name  = $_FILES['pupload']['name']; 
$type  = $_FILES['pupload']['type']; 
$tmp_name = $_FILES['pupload']['tmp_name']; 
echo $name.' : '.$type.' : '.$tmp_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do

```
function var_dump_ret($mixed = null) {
 ob_start();
 var_dump($mixed);
 $content = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 return $content;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the elements of that array are and you know what variables you need to create from all the elements, I think the shortest answer is to use this, given PHP version >= 7.1:

```
list($name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, size) = $_FILES;
```